# Is possible in Android in app purchase create registered members and take fee at the end of the month

Tags: android

Is it possible in Android In-app purchase to create something like registered members or subscribers, to allow the users in that group to download content and to take fee at the end of the month?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, [not with Google Play](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140504). The [Amazon in-app billing](http://www.amazonappstoredev.com/2012/04/announcing-the-in-app-purchasing-api-for-kindle-fire-and-other-android-devices.html) API does support this though.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with [unmanaged purchase](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-purchase-type), but you will need to have server side support for this.

You will have to save the purchases in your own system, keep track of the expiry for each user, etc.

Also, you could do it with managed purchase by creating a new product for each month, but it has its limitations. E.g. you offer monthly subscriptions from the first day to the last of the month and the user buys one on the last day of the month, the he/she will pay the full monthly price for only one day. I do not recommend it.